# Sage X3 cannot acess table values

Tags: 4gl, sage-erp

Hi there can anyone help me in Sage X3.

I made a new table (ZITEMECO) and a new screen (ZITF0) to use inside OITF window but I'm having trouble to read the table, it appears that $LIENS action not working at all, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code of the SPEITF:

```
# Gestão da máscara ITF0 (Específico)

$ACTION
  Case ACTION
    When "OUVRE"      : Gosub OUVRE
    When "APRES_CRE"  : Gosub APRES_CRE
    When "APRES_MOD"  : Gosub APRES_MOD
    When "LIENS"      : Gosub LIENS
    When Default
  Endcase
Return

$OUVRE
  If clalev([F:ZITE]) : Local File ZITMECO[ZITE] : Endif
  Local File ZITMECO [ZITE]

Return

$APRES_CRE
  Gosub APRES_CRE_MOD
Return

$APRES_MOD
  Gosub APRES_CRE_MOD
Return

$APRES_CRE_MOD

  Local Integer LN_EXISTE
  LN_EXISTE=1
  Read [ZITE]ZITE0=[M:ITF0]ITMREF;[M:ITF0]STOFCY
  If fstat=0
   LN_EXISTE=2
  Else
   LN_EXISTE=1
  Endif

    Trbegin[F:ZITE]
          [F:ZITE]ITMREF=[M:ITF0]ITMREF
          [F:ZITE]STOFCY=[M:ITF0]STOFCY
          [F:ZITE]VIDRO=[M:ZITF0]VIDRO
          [F:ZITE]PLASTICO=[M:ZITF0]PLASTICO
          [F:ZITE]PAPEL=[M:ZITF0]PAPEL
          [F:ZITE]ECAL=[M:ZITF0]ECAL
          [F:ZITE]ACO=[M:ZITF0]ACO
          [F:ZITE]ALUM=[M:ZITF0]ALUM
          [F:ZITE]MADEIRA=[M:ZITF0]MADEIRA
          [F:ZITE]OUTROS=[M:ZITF0]OUTROS
   If LN_EXISTE=2

       Rewrite [F:ZITE]
   Else

       Write [F:ZITE]
   Endif
          If fstat=0
            Commit
          Else
            Rollback
          Endif

Return

$LIENS

  Filter [F:ZITE]
  Filter [F:ZITE] Where [F:ZITE]ITMREF=[M:ITF0]ITMREF and [F:ZITE]STOFCY=[M:ITF0]STOFCY

          [M:ZITF0]VIDRO=[F:ZITE]VIDRO
          [M:ZITF0]PLASTICO=[F:ZITE]PLASTICO
          [M:ZITF0]PAPEL=[F:ZITE]PAPEL
          [M:ZITF0]ECAL=[F:ZITE]ECAL
          [M:ZITF0]ACO=[F:ZITE]ACO
          [M:ZITF0]ALUM=[F:ZITE]ALUM
          [M:ZITF0]MADEIRA=[F:ZITE]MADEIRA
          [M:ZITF0]OUTROS=[F:ZITE]OUTROS

  Affzo [M:ZITF0]

Return
```

If anyone can help me, I'm stuck in this... I can write the values in the table and modify them but I'm not able to read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no read in your `$LIENS` block. The filter statement just filter. You have to add a for `[F:ZITE] ... next` or a `Read [F:ZITE]` last or first or `read [F:ZITE]ZITE0=[M:ITF0]ITMREF;[M:ITF0]STOFCY`